# Dynamic host name in publicPath in webpack

Tags: webpack, bundling-and-minification

My config looks like that:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
        publicPath: '//cs0.mysite.com/assets/',
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        chunkfilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js',
    }
    //...
}
```

Instead of placing static `cs0` part in hostname I want to distribute files over ten hosts:

```
 cs[0-9].mysite.com
```

I want to compute hash on asset url to determine which host to append. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multi-compiler feature](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler):

```
var domains = ['cs0', 'cs1', 'cs2', 'cs3', 'cs4', 'cs5', 'cs6', 'cs7', 'cs8', 'cs9'];
module.exports = domains.map(function (domain) {
    return {
        //...
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
            publicPath: '//' + domain + '.mysite.com/assets/',
            filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
            chunkfilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js',
        }
        //...
    };
});
```

Comment: It's about separate configurations for different environments. I need different hostnames in single environment. For example, I want some files to have cs0.mysite.com, some files to have cs1.mysite.com etc., i.e. they has to be uniformly distributed over all hosts.

Comment: You can use this idea any way you want.